# Downloading only some pieces of a torrent file

Tags: bittorrent, video-editing

I was downloading a video file using BitTorrent 7.8 and when the file was downloaded fully i get 3-4 sec (about 106 frames, i counted them using vlc frame by frame method) video that is partially correct (mostly the upper part of the images is correct).

So, i wanted to know if it is possible to only download the pieces that contain that part of video file, i.e, i want to know if there is any way to download only some pieces of a torrent file ?

Also, if it is possible how can i overwrite those frames over the corrupted ones ?

Comment: Well deluge can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BitTorrent, by design, downloads only what's necessary and supports resuming of downloads. If you find that your data seems corrupted, you can do a "force recheck" on the download, which will verify the integrity of the file (with respect to what the file was stated to be when the torrent was created). This force recheck should start (or allow you to start) the download of the bad pieces again.

If the force recheck does not help, then the file was shared with the issue you see in the frames.

To extract certain frames from a video file, you can Stream/Export from VLC. Search on the web for "VLC export frames" for different ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your help but can you tell me if i can extract frames from a partially downloaded video file. If, yes please tell how to do it on windows?

Comment: I've updated the answer for exporting frames from VLC.

Comment: The problem i am having is that the vlc does not play the video of the part that i want the frames of even if i seek it to it. It might have something to do with the fact that it is partially downloaded but i have even downloaded the first part of the file which should contain the headers. Am i missing something?

Comment: Did you do a force recheck in BitTorrent to confirm that the file downloaded correctly and get the corrupted pieces? If not, do that first. Then use VLC to capture those frames.

Comment: Yes i checked that the file parts that have been downloaded are not corrupted. Could there be something else that can cause this problem to arise?

Comment: It would also help if there was a tool/software that can show the entire file to me so that the parts where the frames that i want are present could be taken from. If there is something like that please do tell.

Comment: Assuming the file is not corrupt, you should be able to do it in different ways using different tools. Depending on the format of the file, search on the web for "extract frames <format>" (substitute <format> with the actual file format, like avi or mp4 and so on). You'll get a list of tools and methods to use.

Comment: Sorry for bothering too much but i tried everything but every tool stops extracting images just as the first continuous frames are finished. If there is any tool that can tell a frame given it's time please tell me.